# unauthorized using passport viA WEBSERVICE

Tags: node.js, passport.js, passport-local

I  am using Passport.js but when i go inside else if it gives me error unauthorized. We are calling a webservice here. i want to send response oto webservice when i enter into **else if(exists)**. Any idea?

```
passport.use('local-signup-nti', new LocalStrategy({
        // by default, local strategy uses username and password, we will override with email
        usernameField: 'email',
        passwordField: 'password',
        passReqToCallback: true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
    },
function (req, email, password, done) {
            user.emailExists(email, function (err, exists) {
                if (err)
                    return done(err);
                else if (exists) {
                        req.userDetails=1;
                     return done(err, req.userDetails);
                } else {

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `done` function has to be always called, otherwise, passport won't work propertly.

So, you have to pass the result to the `done` function and pass a callback the `passport.authenticate` function to process the result in the way you want.

See the example:

```
app.get('/protected', function(req, res, next) {
        passport.authenticate('local-signup-nti', function(err, user, info) {
          if (err) { return next(err) }
          if (!user) { return res.redirect('/whereEverYouWant') }
          res.redirect('/toYourWebService');
        })(req, res, next);
      });
```

Hope it's clear!